artifactory jfrog entra ldap auth fails
ldap-config screenshot
Entra LDAPS is failing: LDAP authentication failed
i used this documentation to setup
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-platform-administration-documentation/import-entra-id-groups
for testing the connection i have tried users in this form: admin, company\admin, company.local\admin, admin@company.com, admin@company.onmicrosoft.com not sure which is correct way, but judging by email attribute, it would be the actual email address of the user
I am using a service account with Account Operators level permissions, this user does not have MFA enforced. i have tried using same user as the service account (non-mfa) for the test username / pwd combo. Entra LDAPS testing via LDP.exe is successful
one other thing to note for anyone doing this kind of SSO integration is that my tenant's ip has changed from azure to aws through out a week so i actually had to whitelist both azure and aws, but i dont think thats the reason for the failure
NetRange:       199.59.240.0 - 199.59.243.255
CIDR:           199.59.240.0/22
NetName:        BODIS-COM
bodis is somehow tied to AWS, but earlier in the week it was Azure. at any rate i allowed whitelisted all of the regions subnets from the public list of artifactory for both AWS & Azure. i use artifactory pro instance so i dont get a static IP or any kind of private link setup options with this licensing level.
i do think theres something wrong with the way im setting this up, i looked at every guide i could find for all the AD attributes and queries
tried setting up LDAP secure in artifactory to connect to my Entra tenant, failing with: LDAP authentication failed
